# Difference between ON and WHERE clauses in SQL table joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
select e.last_name, e.hire_date
from employees e join employees m
on (m.last_name = 'Davies')
and (e.hire_date > m.hire_date);

select e.last_name, e.hire_date
from employees e join employees m
on (m.last_name = 'Davies')
where (e.hire_date > m.hire_date);

select e.last_name, e.hire_date
from employees e join employees m
on (e.hire_date > m.hire_date)
where (m.last_name = 'Davies');
```

These three statements have the same result. Apart from the fact that `where` cannot be used exclusively, without using `on`, is there any particular reason to use `where` at all in table joins?

Comment: First: have you checked the query plans?

Comment: [see for example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c30b/5)

Comment: For inner joins, I lay out the code the way I think about it. I put things in ON that are about connecting the two relations together. (Well, relations except they are bags not sets) And put filters in the where clause. In the example you have, the relation between tables is match a row in M with all rows in E that satisfy `e.hire_date > m.hiredate`. That would be in my join. Then selecting the particular row from M, `m.last_name = 'Davies' would go in the where clause. (Which you have as the third query.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main difference is when you are using different joins.

Typically you should see the same result if you were to use inner joins, but once you start using LEFT joins the results will change.

Have a look at the following example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e4b4/6)

[And have a look at the following article (very explanatory)](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

**EDIT for @ShannonSeverance**

*Schema and Test data*

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  ID INT,
  Val VARCHAR(20)
 );

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1,'a');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (2,'a');

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
  ID INT,
  Val VARCHAR(20)
 );

INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1,'a');
```

and Tests

```
SELECT t1.ID,
t1.Val,
t2.ID ID2,
t2.Val Val2
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.Val = t2.Val;

SELECT  t1.ID,
t1.Val,
t2.ID ID2,
t2.Val Val2
FROM Table1 t1,Table2 t2 
WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
 AND t1.Val = t2.Val;

SELECT  t1.ID,
t1.Val,
t2.ID ID2,
t2.Val Val2
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID  AND t1.Val = t2.Val;

SELECT  t1.ID,
t1.Val,
t2.ID ID2,
t2.Val Val2
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID  
WHERE t1.Val = t2.Val;
```

Comment: Great article. Certainly sums up the whole topic pretty well.

Comment: Can we get an example of the difference embedded in the answer here on stack overflow?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance, I did include an example in the SQL Fiddle link. I can copy and past the code from there if you wish...

Comment: The SQL Fiddle link is a pointer to an example, not the example itself.

Answer (score 10):

`where` is a filter which is applied after rows are selected using the join. It is not always the case that a `join ... on` condition is sematically equivalent to a `where` condition. Therefore, yes, there is a particular reason to use a `where` in table joins: when it does the right thing.

---

> ...and by contrast, the `ON` condition executes as the join is being made. `ON` conditions for joins earlier in multi-table joins can cut off millions of unnecessary joins so are generally preferred if semantically correct
>   – [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian)

Comment: ...and by contrast, the `ON` condition executes *as the join is being made*. `ON` conditions for joins earlier in multi-table joins can cut off millions of unnecessary joins so are generally preferred if semantically correct

Comment: I see. 'on' basically SELECTS the rows and 'where' FILTERS them.

Comment: @Jay yes. Your use of `on (m.last_name = 'Davies')` is fairly unusual, in that really belongs in a `where`. Typically `on` is used to identify which rows in one table should be matched up (`join`ed) to which other rows in another table.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'd have to choose astander's answer as it is more descriptive and cleared it up for me.

Comment: @Bohemian _the `ON` executes as the join is being made._ No. The query engine must provide results "as if" all the joins and their respective `ON` clauses were evaluated prior to filtering by the `where` clause. But the optimizer is allowed to reorder things as long as the results match the implied order of execution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `on` usually used for querying more than one table. When making that query, tables must have relationship each other, in general the same value in a specific fields.

`on` will connect that same value, for example:

```
**table1**:

id_name   id_position   name
1         1             john
2         2             doe
3         2             tom
4         3             hawkins

**table2**
id_position   position
1             system analyst
2             programmer

SELECT t1.id_name, t1.name, t2.position
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id_position = t2.id_position

-- RESULT:
id_name   name     position
1         john     system analyst
2         doe      programmer
3         tom      programmer
4         hawkins  NULL            -- NO MATCH IN table 2
```

as we can see `on` will connect table1 and table2 that have same value `id_position`, so it is a little different from what you have been written above.

While `where` can be used in every query and not depends how many tables in that query. In general `where` is used for conditional thing that we want.

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in when the engine performs the filtering. A "where" represents a filter on the computed product of both tables. The "on" keyword specifies how a join is performed. They are not semantically equivalent even if sometimes they both produce the same outcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The `ON` clause defines the relationship between the tables.

- `ON` Clause supports all join types.

The `WHERE` clause describes which rows you are interested in.

- `WHERE` Clause only supports for Inner join not for Outer joins like `LEFT
  JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.